# Error Trying to Add a List that is Implemented into an IF Statement

Tags: java, list, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm trying to add a list so I can print a line of text after a specific event takes place. This is the error I'm getting on line 6.

> Error: Syntax error on token "<", ? expected after this token

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RelativelyPrime {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);  
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    int num1 = scnr.nextInt();
    int num2 = scnr.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Common divisors of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + ":");
    for(int i = 1; i<= Math.min(num1,num2); i++){
      if(num1%i==0 && num2%i==0) {
        System.out.println(i);
        list.add(i);
      }
    }
    if (list.size()<2){
      System.out.print(num1 + " and " + num2 + " are relatively prime.");  
    }
    else {
      System.out.print(num1 + " and " + num2 + " are not relatively prime.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should also import ```List``` and ```ArrayList```? You might change to ```import java.util.*;```. Then it worked for me, but I did not get the same error before. What is your version? Did this help?

Comment: I tried import java.util.*; it still didn't work. I'm using drjava IDE.

Comment: IDE should not be that relevant.. What is your java version? Try ```List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();``` perhaps

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Java 6, or at least are compiling with the language level of Java 6, which does not support the diamond (`<>`) syntax.

If you can upgrade it to at least Java 7 (or the language level thereof), you probably should. If you can't do that, you'd have to repeat the generic specification in the `ArrayList` constructor:

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// Here ---------------------------^
```

Comment: Good catch on that typo @dreamcrash, thanks for the edit